# How to get the token from a request done with Paypal rest-api-sdk-php library

Tags: php, rest, paypal, access-token

I am using [rest-api-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) to make requests to Paypal. When I execute a request it looks something like this:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-74C74934GB935960F"
```

I need to retrieve the token that is used to sign the request.

**Is there a method in the library to get this token?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's the PayPal REST API SDK c# code, you'll need to translate it to PHP.

```
Dictionary<String, String> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<String, String>();
sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox"); // when you're live, change "sandbox" to "live"
String oAuthAccessTokenForPayPal
 = new PayPal.OAuthTokenCredential(yourClientID, yourSecret,
                                   sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
```

PayPal calls your password your "secret".

https://developer.paypal.com/ ... you'll need a PayPal merchant account, and a pair of id/secret for sandbox testing and a second pair for when you go live.

also, each part of your PayPal code must be wrapped with try/catch if you want your code to be robust.

Comment: each token is currently good for 28800 seconds (8 hours), however, PayPal's best practice recommendation with which i agree is to get a new token each time you need one; for each RESTful transaction workflow, that's two tokens you'll require, one before you send your customer to PayPal and a second token after PayPal returns your customer to your website.